# When the Sequences in Databases will be created If the Generator class is Sequence

Tags: hibernate

I am using Custom sequences in my hibernate mapping file. Now the question is when the sequences will be created in the databases if generator class "sequence" is supported by the databases.

Example declaration is as follows:

```
<class name="Employer" table="employers">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">employer_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="name"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are specifying your own custom sequence Hibernate will not create a sequence for you. It will try to find an existing sequence with the name you have specified. If you want Hibernate to handle the sequence generation then skip the param name property and Hibernate will generate the sequence for you.

If you have the following hibernate property set it will generate the sequence for you using your sequence name

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
```

The Hibernate docs of the above property state the following

> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is >created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is >closed explicitly.
>   e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

Comment: You mean to say that when we specify the param tag explicitly to define our own custom sequence, Is that the responsibility of the application developer to create the sequences manually in the database ? take the case I have 100 tables with custom sequences , do I have to create the sequences through script ? hibernate does not help me regarding this? What is the advantage of Custom sequences?

Comment: Updated my answer. do check